# How can I catch all requests starts with /X in AttributeRouting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributerouting

Urls: /X?take=1&skip=4

[GET("X/{request:alpha?}", IsAbsoluteUrl = true)]

[GET("X{request:alpha?}", IsAbsoluteUrl = true)]

[GET("X{request:alpha*}", IsAbsoluteUrl = true)]

does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because using POST Attribute is preventing to GET request handling.

I was using both POST and GET. I've changed them to ROUTE.